# Why there is no LINCR for Redis?

Tags: redis

I wonder why Redis has no command to increment an element in the list?

You can increment a key's value with INCR, you can use HINCRBY to increment an item in the hash set and you can use ZINCRBY to inrement an element of the sorted set. But not in the list.

This puzzles me. Why not?

What was the thinking behind this decision? Lists are "not supposed to be used like this", then why? They work in a very different way from sets? Then what's the big difference?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this and what problem would it solve for you? You would need to locate the element in the list before you could update it.

Comment: @JoeDoherty what I want to do and how I want to do it depends very much on Redis, what it does more efficient and what it does less efficient basically influences my design decisions. I am just learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference is there is no possibility of accessing a given item efficiently in a Redis list. They are implemented as double-linked lists (for big lists) or completely serialized (ziplist optimization, for small lists). By comparison hash and sorted set are implemented using a hash table which allows O(1) amortized complexity for item accesses.

So if such incrementation command would exist for lists, its complexity would be O(n). Not very interesting for just an incrementation.

Note that if you need such feature, you can easily implement it yourself with a server-side Lua script by calling LINDEX and LSET.